# How to put in a file on android to keep location on

Tags: android

So I'm trying to monitor my child location , he likes to turn it off so I can't track him.... specifically how would I write a code to say when he turns off his location, stay on

Or a code that disables its touch

And how would I put it in android, just send the file to the phone, or do I insert it in a rooted phone

Comment: make your own launcher, disable slide down menu, and hide your settings application

Comment: You do realize nothing you do can stop him from just turning off the phone, right?

Answer (score 0):

Good Question. You can create Admin App in advance solution then it can control phone and prevent user (children) to turn off what you set or even prevent uninstalling it.
but If you it's ok to save last available location register broadcast receiver and when GPS turn off get info and write to a file

```
<receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

also you need to add permissions in manifest and request permissions at runtime

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
```

then in class get location info and write it to file

```
     public class ReceiverGPS extends BroadcastReceiver{

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == false){
                //write file here
}
        }
        }
```

Comment: When you say write file here, what would I input there, and where would I store this file on android

Comment: write location info into a file read this tutorial  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: I'm going to learn that whole site, thank you for taking the time to keep my family safer.

Comment: i can help you more with one of my private android project. email me or open chat with me

Comment: That won't prevent him from turning GPS off

Comment: What do you mean gabe

Comment: @hellomoto This would just let you know when GPS turned on or off (and it wouldn't just be when he turned it off, it would also fire if he went indoors and lost line of sight to the satellites).  It wouldn't prevent him from turning it off.  THe only thing that can do that is a custom ROM.  Maybe a device ownership policy, but I'm not sure if even that can.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes I mentioned it will help to get last available location info. And also mention there should be Admin App to Prevent this operation

Comment: How do I get ahold of you to discuss the operation more Elias

Comment: email me or just search my name on google :D x102x96x@gmail.com